# How to remove the special character for Enter

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputtext

I am trying to remove special char for enter. When I copy past 2 paragraph the space between 2 para is getting converted to special char. I need to remove it in LWC, do anyone have nay idea how to solve it.

> It’s that easy!Once the Team Chall

The special char between easy and once word. The real for looks like below img
[image]

[image]

Comment: Anu, have you considered a regular expression like `someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");`?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways you could approach this... what do you want to *include* or *remove* from the text input.
Assuming you are looking for code... here is a working component for you to play with.  I have used the include only alpha characters because this allows you to see it work easily, just type "$" or "#" and you will see...nothing.

You can just as easily use @jefersonchaves suggestion, which probably is a better idea for free text.

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class TestText extends LightningElement {
    fixedInput;

    handleYourFieldChange(event) {
        let text = event.detail.value;
        this.fixedInput = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Your Field">
        <p>
            <lightning-input
                name="yourField"
                label="Your Field"
                onchange={handleYourFieldChange}
            ></lightning-input>
        </p>
        <p slot="footer">{fixedInput}</p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Finally, there are lots of bells and whistles to the lightning-input
For example, you could handle validation in the lightning-input and give users useful feedback. 
See **https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example**